# Необходимо скачать файл нажимая на кнопку

Tags: php, wordpress, php7, yandex-disk

помогите мне пожалуйста. Я пытаюсь запросить файл через php, после нажатия на кнопку я должен отправить запрос на загрузку и получить файл от disk.yandex.ru, у меня уже есть ссылка на скачивание и если я её просто введу в адресную строку вручную всё ок, но стоит мне перенаправить или сделать это ссылкой, то мне выдаёт ошибку 403. Подскажите пожалуйста как через ajax, отправить запрос на закачку файла, то есть мне надо чтобы человек, который нажал на кнопку получил файл который лежит по определенной ссылке.

Comment: Как минимум, нужен атрибут download `<a href="https://domain/cool.jpg" download>`

Comment: А вообще, лучше на ссылку посмотреть

Comment: Скорее всего вы парсите ссылку на файл с яндекс диска? Там ссылка генерируется автоматически, в ней есть токен с привязкой к IP или сессии. Другой пользователь не сможет воспользоватся ссылкой. Разве что скачивайте файл себе на сервер, а потом отдавайте юзеру. Или проксируйте файл через PHP, но это будет немного накладно в плане ресурсов.

Comment: @ДавидМанжула речь идёт об общедоступной ссылке, скорее всего. Вряд ли дело в токене.

Comment: @ДавидМанжула все верно написал... Дополню ответ еще тем, сессия яндекса привязана к IP. Так, что даже украденая сессия с другого IP работать не будет. И еще дополнительно возможно и HTTP-REFERER проверяется (на mail.ru, например, точно есть блокировка по HTTP-REFERER, возможно и на yandex есть). То есть с пустым REFERER все работает (с адресной строки), но при клике на ссылку - нет.